# Why does 'delete()' method in CrudRepository require entity with unique id?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

In the description of the `delete` method in `org.springframework.data.repository,CrudRepository` interface it is written only that it deletes a given entity and that it accepts entity object itself.

It specifies nothing about entity's id needing to be unique.

However, this method works only when entity has an unique id. If the table may have multiple rows with the same id, this method fails when entity whose id is not unique is attempted to be deleted (at least in my case).

Now I understand that it is a very bad thing that an id is not unique in the table, but, in theory, it should work since this method accepts the entire entity as a parameter, and every entity (when all its columns are combined) in my table is unique. There are no two identical rows in a table since table has an unique constraint on a combination of all its columns.

Sure, there are other methods, like `deleteById` which would fail since they only accept id as a parameter and not the whole entity and since id is not unique, Spring does not know which entity to delete. Sure.

But why `delete` method fails when it should be able to distinguish between entities with the same id since it accepts the whole entitiy as a parameter (thus giving it access to all other columns of the entity and not just the id column)?

Comment: Because you dont want 99.9% of the repositories suffer from a bad design choice of the remaining 0.1%

Answer (score 2):

The requirement for the JPA id is that it is a primary key i.e. uniquely identifies the row. If you do not follow this, bad things will happen. You can have a composite primary key though, as it seems your row is identified by multiple columns. Look into `@Embeddable`/`@EmbeddedId` mappings for this purpose.